# how to install apc cache on macOS with xampp

Tags: macos, xampp, apc

I am unable set up PHP APC module on a Mac running OSX High Sierra using XAMPP.

These are the steps I followed to get it installed:

`cd /tmp`

`wget http://pecl.php.net/get/APC-3.1.4.tgz`

`tar -xf APC-3.1.4.tgz`

`cd APC-3.1.4`

`/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/phpize-5.6.32`

`./configure --with-php-config=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php-config-5.6.32`

its showing

> ./configure: No such file or directory please help me to install the
>   same.